# Как очистить поток ввода в С++?

Tags: c++, ввод, linux

Ситуация такая: я учусь программировать на С++, определённое время делал делал примеры в Visual Studio, потом перешёл на NetBeans под Linux. Как и, думаю, у любого, кто осуществил такой переход, у меня возникла небольшая проблема с отсутствием функции getch() из conio.h. Вроде бы, проблему я решил вот так (естественно, решение не моё):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <termios.h>
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int getche()
 {
         char ch;
         struct termios oldt, newt;
         tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldt );
         newt = oldt;
         newt.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
         tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt );
         ch = getchar();
         tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt );
         cout << ch;
         return ch;
 }
```

Далее я использовал предыдущий код в этой функции:

```
void my_cin(int& number, char ch = '\n')
{
     number = 0;
     char numeral;
     while (1)
     {
        numeral = getche();
    if (numeral == ch)
        break;
    number *= 10;
    number += numeral - 48;
     }
 }
```

И использовал функцию в этом коде:

```
void fraction::get_fract()
{
    my_cin(numer, '/');
    my_cin(denom);
}
```

В моей программе пользователь по запросу вводит несколько дробей в формате "5/6", соответственно числителю (numer) присваивается значение 5, знаменателю (denom) - 6. Проблема в том, что при вводе второй и последующих дробей я получаю неверное значение числителя из-за того, что в буфере остаётся `"\n"` после ввода предыдущей дроби. Я пробовал чистить поток используя в различных сочетаниях:
    1. cin.clear()
    2. cin.ignore()
    3. while(getchar != '\n');
Ни одно решение не помогло. Пожалуйста, скажите, какие есть ещё варианты решения? Ну или, может быть, вы знаете как правильно использовать код из пунктов 1-3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял проблему, то   Вы в промежутке между вызовами get_fract() читаете что-то в духе:

```
 string s;
 cin >> s;
```

(иначе "лишним" `'\n'` взяться вроде неоткуда).

Тогда просто вызывайте вот такой фрагмент

```
 int dummy; my_cin(dummy);
```

в тех местах, где требуется очистка потока, включая `'\n'`.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, проблема решилась банальным добавлением cin.get() после запроса о желании продолжить ввод в цикле. Действительно dummy. Спасибо.

Comment: @vchslv13: `dummy` — это традиционное название для переменной, значение которой нами игнорируется. :)